# My SQL table won't update

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am making a site and I am having some trouble with the update page. The page updates existing posts.

Here is the code that fails:

```
$result = mysql_query("UPDATE php_blog SET timestamp='$timestamp',
title='$title', entry='$entry', WHERE id='$id' LIMIT 1") or die(mysql_error());
```

When I press the "update" button on my form I get this SQL message:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE id='9' LIMIT 1' at line 1

but I have no idea what it means. I've checked that place but can't find anything wrong... Help? Thanks

Comment: You have an extra comma -- remove the comma before WHERE.

Comment: Please consider using prepared statements.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Answer (score 2):

You have an extra comma before your WHERE statement.  Your SQL should look like this:

```
UPDATE php_blog 
SET timestamp='$timestamp', title='$title', entry='$entry' 
WHERE id='$id' LIMIT 1
```

Please note, mysql_ functions have been deprecated:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Comment: @user2096683 -- no problem, glad we could help :)

Answer (score 1):

Remove the comma before `WHERE`:

```
$result = mysql_query("UPDATE php_blog SET timestamp='$timestamp', 
    title='$title',
    entry='$entry' WHERE id='$id' LIMIT 1") 
    or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks man :) Worked :D Love you!

Answer (score 0):

remove the comma before the `WHERE` clause like that

```
$result = mysql_query("UPDATE php_blog SET timestamp='$timestamp', title='$title',entry='$entry' WHERE id='$id' LIMIT 1") or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

The question to your answer: Remove the comma before the `WHERE`

But you are lucky you have that problem and post it here. Your code is very vulnerable and you should really learn how to use prepared statements.

Also google "SQL injection" to understand the problem.